# Does Django CMS Support ASGI?

Tags: django, django-cms, asgi

It seems like it should, given it supports Django 3, but I can't find any information about this at all.

Searching the Django docs, the Django CMS docs, Google, here. Nothing relating to django cms specifically and asgi are returned.

Answer (score 1):

There's no async in django-cms yet. You should still be able to use ASGI, because that's just django, but from django-cms itself, you won't get async views or anything like that.

That's still part of the roadmap and the things we'd like to have, but the focus recently has been shipping a new major version. We'd likely also need some contributors who work regularly with async so that support/features for it can be guided in a sensible manner.

And I say "we", as technical lead for the Django CMS Association.